# How to set variable ng-src within one iframe using Angular Js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, iframe

I was get "sitename" Dynamically in li tag ,on click of that i want to open "link" in iframe.

The Following json formated data i got in response
         Data in response:

> ```
>    [{
>        "SrNo":1,
>        "id":1,
>        "sitename":"Tutorial Poin",
>        "link":"http://www.tutorialspoint.com",
>     },
>     {
>         "SrNo":2,
>         "id":6,
>         "sitename":"W3Schools",
>         "link":"http://www.w3schools.com",
>      },]
> ```

```
 HTML Code::
```

> ```
>  <tr>
>  <td style="width: 11%; vertical-align: top;">
>     <ul id="ultabs" ng-model="ultabs">
>       <li ng-repeat="site in sites">
>       <a href="#frameDiv" ng-click="navigate(site.link)">{{site.sitename}}</a>
>       </li>
>     </ul>
>       </td>
>       <td style="width: 80%; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
>         <div id="frameDiv" style="margin-top: 5px;">
>         <iframe id="Iframe" ng-model="Iframe" ng-src="{{myLink}}"></iframe>
>         </div>    </td></tr>
> ```

```
Conroller code::
```

> ```
> var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
>
>                     //app.filter('trustAsResourceUrl', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
>                         //    return function (val) {
>                         //        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
>                         //    };
>                         //}])
>                         app.controller('formCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
>                             (function init() {
>                                 $http({
>                                     method: 'POST',
>                                     url: "../Ajax/Ajax_Mastermanagement_StudyLinks",
>                                     params: { mode: 'getData' }
>                                 }).then(function mySucces(response) {
>                                     $scope.sites = response.data;
>                                     $scope.myLink = response.data[0].link;
>                                 }, function myError(response) {
>                                     $scope.message = response.statusText;
>                                 });
>                             })();
>
>                             $scope.navigate = function (link) {
>        /* $('#Iframe').attr("src",link);<==This codeworking well,But i want to set "ng-src" attribute in iframe using AngularJs.*/
>                             }
>                         });
> ```

to get ng-src in iframe I also try the Filter But when I add filter's code then I even can't got the data in response.

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you please create a fiddle or plunker that reproduce the issue. by looking at the code it should works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a function defined and pass the url to it,

**JS:**

```
 $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <md-button ng-click="selectMuppet(it)" ng-class="{'selected' : it === selected }">
     <img ng-src="{{trustSrc(it.link)}}" class="face" alt="">
      {{it.sitename}}
   </md-button>
```

Working [`APP`](http://plnkr.co/edit/4XnBFFDsOTx8ULFgAj57?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you sir, But here i m using iframe and i can't use "link" or "sitename" bcoz i used ng-repeate in <li> tag so i can't directly used "link" in iframe

Comment: @ShubhraJoshi I don't get you

Comment: Sir may be u are giving me right answer but i can't got how to implement in my code..Sir i m new in developing and also in angularjs..
  
  here i used "ng-repeat=site in sites" in <li> tag then i thought that i used "site.link" or "site.sitename" in only <li> tag, but as ur solution u suggest me to use "link" and "sitename" in ng-src of <iframe> where i don't have a loop like in <li> tag..
  
  so sir plz suggest me that how can i set ng-src in iframe??

Comment: try with this    <iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(it.link)}}" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>

Comment: @ShubhraJoshi Mark as answer if it had helped you

Answer (score 0):

okk I found it....:)

Controller change

> Add $sce(service) in controllercode
>
> app.controller('formCtrl',function ($scope, $http, $sce){
>
> ```
>   .....
>   $scope.myLink = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(response.data[0].link);
>   .....});
> ```

navigate funtion

> $scope.navigate = function (link) {
>         $scope.myLink = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(link);  }